# How to run multiCapabilities reading configuration parameters from the configuration file

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, protractor, mocha.js

I have one file of config which runs tests in one browser using capabilities.
Now I have created one more separate config file which contains multiCapabilites and will run same tests in multiple browsers.

I want to optimize configs so I second config file I write multiCapabilities for first config and used

delete firstConfig['capabilities'];

to ignore the capabilities from first config and use all other params from firstConfig and use multiCapabilities from 2nd config and run.

Expected result:
params in configs should not be duplicated in both configs, only multiCapabilities is the change, rest of config is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use a base configuration file

Having a base configuration file and another file that extends from it might be a better approach. For this example, we will look at my [base configuration file](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/angular2Conf.js):

```
var env = require('./environment');

// This is the configuration for a smoke test for an Angular TypeScript application.
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: env.seleniumAddress,

  framework: 'jasmine',

  specs: [
    'ng2/async_spec.js'
  ],

  capabilities: env.capabilities,

  baseUrl: env.baseUrl,
  allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
  getPageTimeout: 120000,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000
  }
};
```

### Create a second config from the base config

From there, we did something similar to your question where we removed the capabilities and added multicapabilities. (https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/ciNg2Conf.js). In addition, since we were running on Sauce Labs, we also decided to increase our timeouts.

```
exports.config = require('./angular2Conf.js').config;

exports.config.sauceUser = process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME;
exports.config.sauceKey = process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY;
exports.config.seleniumAddress = undefined;

// TODO: add in firefox when issue #2784 is fixed
exports.config.multiCapabilities = [{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'tunnel-identifier': process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER,
    'build': process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER,
    'name': 'Protractor suite tests',
    'version': '54',
    'selenium-version': '2.53.1',
    'chromedriver-version': '2.26',
    'platform': 'OS X 10.11'
  }];
exports.config.capabilities = undefined;
exports.config.allScriptsTimeout = 120000;
exports.config.getPageTimeout = 120000;
exports.config.jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval = 120000;
```

I hope that helps.

### Update:

Per comments below, setting the config.capabilities to undefined did not work; however, setting config.capabilities to false did work.

Comment: Thanks @cnishina, yes implementing this way is a good idea. the configuration works but the problem:

In second config file: I have defined multiCapabilites which will run parallel browser for parallel tests but whenever I run second config: it takes capabilites and specs parameters from first file in consideration and run tests 
while I want it to ignore capabilites and specs parameters from first config file and consider these both from second config file, kindly share how can I ignore capabilites & specs parameters from first config file when I run second config file.

Comment: exports.config.capabilities = undefined;

didn't worked for me:

exports.config.capabilities = false;

worked, and working fine now, Thanks for help.

Comment: Great! As long as it got you on the right path. I'll update my answer.

Comment: True, 
Thanks @cnishina

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a capabilities provider to define vary capabilities, and exports a function to return a capabilities array according to the cmd line params.

```
// capabilities.provider.js

var capabilities = {
  chrome: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  chrome-headless {
    browserName: 'chrome',
  },
  firefox: {
    browsername: 'firefox'
  },
  ...
 };

exports.evaluate=function(){

  var caps = 'chrome';

  process.argv.slice(3).forEach(function(kvp){
    if(kvp.includes('--caps=')) {
      caps = kvp.split('=')[1] || caps;
    }
  })

  var _caps = [];

  caps.split(',').forEach(function(cap){
     if(Object.keys(capabilities).includes(cap)) {
        _caps.push(capabilities[cap])
     }
  })

  return _caps;
};
```

protractor config.js

```
var capsProvider = require('./capabilities.provider');

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: '',

  framework: 'jasmine',

  specs: [
    'ng2/async_spec.js'
  ],

  params: {

  },

  multiCapabilities: capsProvider.evaluate(),

  baseUrl: env.baseUrl,
  allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
  getPageTimeout: 120000,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000
  }
};
```

Specify caps from cmd line:

`protractor config.js --caps=chrome,firefox,ie,safari`